# How can I pass xunit test results to a custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes, xunit, xunit.net

I have created a TestCaseAttribute, which has an After method. This attribute receives test rail case Id and run Id, and needs to send results to testrail.

The issue is that I cannot configure how to pass the results to the After method, or how can I update the attribute properties from within the test.

Following my Attribute class:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class TestCaseAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    public ulong CaseId { get; private set; }
    public ulong RunId { get; private set; }

    public TestCaseAttribute(ulong caseId, ulong runId)
    {
        CaseId = caseId;
        RunId = runId;
    }


    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {

        TestRail2.PostResult(RunId, CaseId, "Passed", message: "Test Passed");

    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure xUnit.net does not expose the results at the level you are looking/proposing, unfortunately.

You can instrument the discovery and running with a TestRunner override for a test type like so:
https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/ObservationExample/XunitExtensions/ObservationTestCaseRunner.cs

The closest thing to manage global post-processing without changing your tests goes like so:
https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/TestRunner/Program.cs

I guess your real answer lies either in between the two or somewhere else in that set of samples; there's examples of pretty much anything that's possible in there.

Comment: Thank you I will try to combine